# How to change the label of X-Axis in chart for flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

Hello guys i'm using syncfusion_flutter_charts package for draw a bar chart and i want to know how to change the X-Axis to be an icon insted of text is that can be done using this package?

if it can be done can you provide me with an example if not is there are any package can do what i want?

I tried to change the String in ColumnSeries to be widget but it didn't work

```
ColumnSeries<SalesData, Widget>(
    dataSource: columnData,
    xValueMapper: (SalesData salesData, _) => salesData.x,
    yValueMapper: (SalesData salesData, _) => salesData.y,
    color: Colors.white,
    trackColor: Colors.transparent,
    isTrackVisible: true,
    dataLabelSettings:
    const DataLabelSettings(color: Colors.white),
    isVisibleInLegend: false,
    spacing: 1.5
)
```

[Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6pn1.png)

Instead of Text here i want it to be icons

Comment: Do you mean axis labels? Can you provide an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Soliev I Edit the question and added image